# Get projects with only one Admin which is a given User

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have the following entities:

```
public class Project {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<ProjectRole> ProjectRoles { get; set; }
}

public class User {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<ProjectRole> ProjectRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectRole {
  public Int32 ProjectId { get; set; }
  public Int32 UserId { get; set; }
  public String Role { get; set; }
  public Project Project { get; set; }
  public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Given an `userId` I need to find all projects that:
1. Have only one `ProjectRole` with `Role` equal to `Admin`;
2. The `UserId` of the `Admin` is equal to given `userId`.

```
var userId = 1;

var projects = context.Projects.Where(x => x.ProjectRoles.Count(y => y.Role == "Admin") == 1 && ??
```

I started by getting all projects that have only one role equal to `Admin`.

What I am missing is making sure that ProjectRole's `UserId`is equal to given `userId`.

How can I do this?

Comment: That won't work ... If you have 2 Admins being `UserId=1` and `UserId=2` your count will return 1. So  `UserId=1` is Admin but it is not unique. Am I missing something on your code?

Comment: But I am not looking for projects that have only one ProjectRole. I am looking for projects that have only one ProjectRole Admin and that ProjectRole userId is the given userId. Maybe changing your first condition to x.ProjectRoles.Count(x => x.Role == “Adnin”) == 1 && ... Or am I thinking incorrectly? not sure if it possible to simplify the query

Comment: `context.ProjectRoles.GroupBy(p => new { p.Role, p.UserId }).Where(g => g.Key.Role == "Admin" && g.Count() == 1 && g.All(z => z.UserId == userId));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is more interesting than it looks initially, mainly because there are many straightforward solutions, but all they need to execute 2 subqueries per project in order to satisfy the 2 requirements.

For instance, since the

```
x.ProjectRoles.Count(y => y.Role == "Admin")
```

condition ensures that there is only 1 Admin per project, additional condition like

```
&& x.ProjectRoles.Any(y => y.Role == "Admin" && y.UserId == userId)
```

or

```
&& x.ProjectRoles.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Role == "Admin").UserId == userId
```

or

```
&& x.ProjectRoles.Where(y => y.Role == "Admin").Select(y => y.UserId).Contains(userId)
```

will ensure that the single Admin is the given user.

Another way is to use criteria like this

```
x.ProjectRoles.Any(y => y.Role == "Admin" && y.UserId == userId)
    && !x.ProjectRoles.Any(y => y.Role == "Admin" && y.UserId != userId)
```

in other words, project has the given user as Admin and has no other Admins.

Actually the `y.UserId == userId` condition can be removed

```
x.ProjectRoles.Any(y => y.Role == "Admin")
    && !x.ProjectRoles.Any(y => y.Role == "Admin" && y.UserId != userId)
```

i.e. project has Admins and also has no other Admins than the given user, hence it has only 1 admin and it is the given user.

Anyway, as mentioned at the beginning, all these execute 2 subqueries per project. 
Now, if you are wondering (and that's the interesting part for me) if this be achieved with single subquery, the answer is yes, with condition like this:

```
x.ProjectRoles.Where(y => y.Role == "Admin")
    .Min(y => y.UserId == userId ? (int?)1 : 0) == 1
```

Here is why. After `Where` clause we have the set of the Admins of the project. Now the expression

```
.Min(y => y.UserId == userId ? 1 : 0)
```

will return

- `null` when the set is empty (there are no Admins)
- 0 when there is Admin other than the given user
- 1 when the given user is Admin and there are no other Admins

As we can see, only the return value `1` satisfied both requirements, hence `== 1` will achieve the desired filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
context.ProjectRoles
       .GroupBy(p => new { p.Role, p.UserId })
       .Where(g => g.Key.Role == "Admin" &&
                   g.Count() == 1 &&
                   g.All(z => z.UserId == userId)
             );
```